# PHP session variables taking a while to register change

Tags: php, session, caching, time

I've noticed an issue with my PHP session variables.

If a variable is set on one page it is not instantly visible on another. It might take a few reloads of the page before the new value of the session variable shows up. I'm sending them back to a script and logging the value to the console to see it.

Is this normal? The session value is critical to what appears on the screen to the user so it's important it has the right value.

I should add that I've instructed browsers not to cache the page too.

Comment: Strange behavior. Have you tried to test it without any other code? (only set session variable and display on other page?)

Comment: That would mean PHP has a hard time writing the session (in case you use the files based handler, it would be to disk, which may indicate HD problems, or a session that is _way_ bigger then is healthy). What session handler _are_ you using, and what is the typical storage size of those sessions? However, it could also mean the original script is still busy with other stuff during that time, calling `session_write_close()` as soon as you're done with the session variables could help in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Are you redirecting via a header('Location: ') call after setting these variables?

As wrikken has suggested, you should call session_write_close() before your redirect.

In addition to this, after your redirect ensure that you call exit; e.g.

header('Location: newurl.php');

exit;

Otherwise your original page will continue processing.